# Cannot run the program in the Qt Creator environment

Tags: c++, qt, qml

My Qt Creator Verison is 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019 64bit) And I want using Qt 6.2 rc

Now I have a project that can be compiled normally but cannot run in the Qt Creator environment.But I manually run this program in Explorer, it can work normally. That is to say, Qt Creator built it but this software cannot be debugged in Qt

By the way, this project can run normally when it is newly created. Then I introduced spdlog and sql related libraries in this project (but not used), and after adjusting the directory structure, it cannot be used in Qt Creator.

Console Output:

```
17:06:23: Starting E:\Code\Clion\CadenceLibQML\CadenceLibQML\build-CadenceLibQML-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\CadenceLibQML.exe ...
17:06:23: The program ends abnormally
17:06:23: The process was ended forcefully.
17:06:23: E:\Code\Clion\CadenceLibQML\CadenceLibQML\build-CadenceLibQML-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\CadenceLibQML.exe crashed.
```

Comment: You say: *MSVC 2019 64bit* but in the log it indicates that you use mingw: *Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit*

Comment: This version number refers to the Qt Creator main program, which is the IDE, not Qt Kits. And I have been using this combination normally until I used Qt 6.2 rc kit and this problem occurred.

Comment: Although it is not clear why, but I solved the problem
The solution is to delete the folder build-CadenceLibQML-Desktop_Qt_6_2_0_MinGW_64_bit-Debug, and then rebuild it.
(Of course, I adjusted the generation of third-party libraries before this, and I don't know if it is related to this)